# What does the CPU do in AI model training?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, cpu

I'm new to computing and even newer still to AI model training. However I am wondering the role of the CPU during training of LLM. I'm aware that the CPUs are good for performing strings of complicated tasks one at a time while the GPU's parallelisation means that it can perform mutiple less complicated tasks at the same time. If AI model training mainly consists of the matrix multiplication (which is handled by the GPUs), the input and out is managed by the DPUs. What is the role of the CPU during the AI training phase?